# Formula of probability theory

Tags: probability, statistics, summation

So I'm currently learning Probability Theory on my own and at the beginning of the syllabus, there is a formula that I need to prove (by induction). The problem is that I just don't even understand how to compute the summation. Could someone help me show how you compute it, like for example for m = 3 in the sigma notation ? I just get confused with the second sigma and those indices.

Thanks in advance

[image: The formula I have to prove]

Comment: For the case $m=3$ a Venn diagram with $A_1,A_2,A_3$ might help ;)

Comment: This is a version of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Oh alright that should help, thanks y'all

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The brackets at the end literally say *Formula of the in- and exclusion*

Comment: @Henry  Thanks for translating.

Comment: For $m = 3:$ $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) =$ $P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3) -$ $P(A_1A_2) - P(A_1A_3) - P(A_2A_3) + $ $P(A_1A_2A_3).$ // Venn Diagram with three circles: If you add the three probabilities, you have double counted three 'lens shaped' regions (so you subtract those overlaps). But now the central almost triangular region has been counted thrice and subtracted thrice, to add it back. // Next time, put the Dutch through Google translate or something similar, to get something close to the English translation.